# npm run serve increases port instead of reusing :8080

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I have a problem with `npm run serve` because it does not use port **8080**, instead after every `npm run serve` the port is increased so now I'm on **8091**.

But I use `django-webpack-loader` which needs to use **8080**.

```
(feedbot) milano@milano-desktop:~/PycharmProjects/feedbot/frontend$ npm run serve 

> frontend@0.1.0 serve /home/milano/PycharmProjects/feedbot/frontend
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 1125ms     


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8091/ <<<<<< HERE YOU CAN SEE THE PORT
  - Network: http://0.0.0.0:8080/


                                                                10:37:55 PM
```

I use this in my template:

```
 <div id="app">
            <app></app>
 </div>
 {% render_bundle 'index' %}
```

I can see in inspect that `render_bundle` renders wrong url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.js
```

How do I make it work? The `npm` increases `port` instead of reusing `8080`.

So either I make `django-webpack-loader` to somehow recognize which port is in use or `npm` to reuse 8080.

**EDIT**

```
sudo netstat -ap | grep :8080
```

returns nothing so I don't understand why the server is not using it

Comment: I'm no `netstat` expert but I tried running the same command as you and it didn't find my server running either, even though it definitely is running. I tried `sudo netstat -peanut | grep LISTEN | grep 8080` and that found it.